# GeoGebra - X and Y orientation

Tags: geogebra

Trying to use GeoGebra for the first time. Currently it shows the x and y as in the below image

[image]

but I prefer the x and y orientation as below as it would be easy to visualise with x-axis popping out of the board

[image]

what settings need to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

Look in settings for the "y-axis vertical" option

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you cannot specify the default settings, but you can change the view orientation with the following command.
SetViewDirection(Vector((1, 1, 1)))
https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/SetViewDirection_Command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).